# cakephp array_filter callback function not found

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a cakephp application, in one of my controllers, I have a function `_filter_callback` to be used as callback to the php function [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) like this:

```
class TestClassController extends AppController
{
     var $name = 'TestClass';

     ....

     function test_fn()
     {
         ...
         array_filter($my_array, '_filter_callback');
     }

     function _filter_callback($val)
     {
          // callback logic here...
     }
}
```

The problem I have is that my function `_filter_callback` cannot be found by `array_filter` in my controller because I get the following error:

```
Warning: array_filter() expects parameter 2 to be a valid callback, 
function '_filter_callback' not found or invalid function name
```

Does anybody know how I can make `array_filter` aware of my callback function in a cakephp application?

Comment: Can you give us an example of your code?

Comment: Is it in the same scope?

Comment: yes, everything is in the same class (view edit).

Comment: No not in the same class. in the same **scope**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is the function in the global scope? If not - it has to be.
If the body of the function is simple (in most cases) try to use anonymous functions as of PHP > 5.3 - http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

or use the create_function

http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php

You can then inject this as a parameter without declaring one-use global function.

Example of filtering all elements smaller than 10:

```
array_filter($array, create_function('$a', 'return $a > 10;'));
```

EDIT:
I can see now that you are trying to call method of the object. You must specify the instance. Try this:

```
array_filter($my_array, array($this, '_filter_callback'));
```

Comment: Wow, `array_filter($my_array, array($this, '_filter_callback'));` WORKED!!, Thank you very much. I didn't know that syntax `array($this, 'a_function'`);. Can you give me a link or something that explains that syntax please?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php See Example #4

Answer (score 0):

A valid PHP callback definition is:

1. A string with the name of the global function in it: `'functionName'`
2. An array with the instance of the object to be used as the first element, and a string with the name of the method to be called inside this object as the second element: `array($object, 'method')`
3. A string with a static method call: `'StaticClass::methodName'`
4. An array with a class name as a string as first element, and a static function name as second element: `array('StaticClass', 'methodName')`
5. A lambda function, inlined: `function(){ /*do stuff*/ }`
6. A lambda function in a variable: `$lambda`

`is_callable()` can be used to check whether the argument can be called or not.

Note that using callbacks is subject to visibility. You usually cannot use private or protected methods as an argument to PHP functions. They act from a global perspective and cannot access those methods from outside.